# Sentinal While Loop RTE

Tags: java

I have been trying to write a sentinal controlled while loop in java to add numbers, which are taken as input by the user. The loop must end when the user
enters "add".

The code is given below, the code does not show any compile error but there's a runtime Error. I would like to know what was the mistake I have done.

Thank you

```
// Sentinal while is used if we dont know how many numbers we are going to add

import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class sentinalWhile {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String numberStr;
        double number,total=0;
        final String SENTINAL = "add";
        numberStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number to add (press add to quit):");
        number = Double.parseDouble(numberStr);
        while(numberStr.compareTo(SENTINAL)!=0)
        {
            total += number ;
            numberStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number to add(-999 to quit)");
            number = Double.parseDouble(numberStr);

        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total is:"+" "+total);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "add"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at sentinalWhile.main(sentinalWhile.java:11)
```

Comment: If you're getting errors, you need to say what they are.

Comment: Also, instead of `compareTo`, I think you should be using `equals`. I suppose they probably do the same thing, but the usage here just looks odd.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "add"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at sentinalWhile.main(sentinalWhile.java:11)
i dont know much , but i think these are the errors

Comment: Please edit errors into the question and format them so they're readable. If you're getting a number format exception though, that means the string you're parsing can't be interpreted as a number. Apparently you're trying to parse "add" as a number, which obviously isn't going to work.

Comment: Your application error says.

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "add"

this means that is is trying to turn your String add into a Double which it cannot do.

Use SENTINAL as -999 and see how you get on.

Comment: yeah , it works with -999, but i want the user to type a meaningful string like "stop" or "add" to add the inputs

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove "add" from the end of the string that you receive from the input dialog.

`numberStr = numberStr.substring(0, numberStr.lastIndexOf("add"));`

Then try to parse the double out of this string.

`number = Double.parseDouble(numberStr);`

Note that if the user enters a non-number string in the input dialog (e.g. 234sdfsf5500add), you will still get that exception. However, it will work fine for the normal inputs (100add).